# How can i fetch tally custom report data by xml

Tags: php, xml, curl, tally

I want to get the tally custom (user defined report)report data using xml.
Like:- Get the Outstandings report, Purchase Bills Pending, Sales Bills Pending report etc.

```
<ENVELOPE>  
  <HEADER>  
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>  
  </HEADER>  
  <BODY>  
    <EXPORTDATA>  
      <REQUESTDESC>  
        <!-- Specify the Report Name here -->  
        <REPORTNAME>My Own Report</REPORTNAME>  
        <STATICVARIABLES>  
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>  
        </STATICVARIABLES>  
      </REQUESTDESC>  
    </EXPORTDATA>  
  </BODY>  
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: Try to keep your sample code what you have done so far to achieve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

read [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?rq=1) , there's plenty of ways to parse XML in PHP. for example, in your case, to get the REPORTNAME one could use DOMDocument,

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml);
$report_name=$domd->getElementsByTagName("REPORTNAME")->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: It's tally related. I need my custom report data by xml request

Comment: @MD.AshrafulAlam oh, so your question is about how to generate the request? in which case, voting to close your question as a duplicate was wrong

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/integration_capabilities/case_study_1.htm) a link for how to request a report via XML:

The code is as below. You would need replace the  tag to have the name of your custom report.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Data</TYPE>
<ID>Trial Balance</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

- Assuming you have a way to ping Tally via their port (usually localhost:9000), either via CURL or PHP. A simple way to do this is to store this XML in a file (say my_report.xml), [install curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and then just run the command

  ***curl -X POST localhost:9000 --data @my_report.xml***
- The custom report should also be loaded via TDL in Tally for this to work.